# How to remove ionic app web-view from being read with talk-back or other screen reader?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working on the improving the accessibility of my app, is there any way to remove the alt tag or other attribute from the app web-view element/ where is the web-view element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `aria-hidden="true"` to the elements you don't want read by the screen reader.

E.g.

```
<ion-list aria-hidden="true">...</ion-list>
```

[Reference](https://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201205/hiding_visible_content_from_screen_readers_with_aria-hidden/)